# ¿se puede hacer una gráfica interactiva con spyder y código python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder

Un saludo compañeros, hace un tiempo realice un código que gráfica una curva par vs velocidad de un motor de inducción y todo bien, la gráfica se muestra como corresponde, pero.. me gustaría crear un botón deslizable para ir cambiando cierto valor de la variable y que se vaya observando como cambia la gráfica a medida que altero el valor.

¿se puede hacer con simple código o necesito crear una GUI?

se que en Ipython se puede, pero necesito hacer en spyder para desarrollar una APP posteriormente.

Comment: matplotlib tiene sliders: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html ademas de otros widgets: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/widgets_api.html

Comment: copie el segundo código que me compartiste y me muestra la gráfica, pero no me permite modificar el parámetro, no se si sea porque lo estoy realizando en spyder

Comment: ¿Has arrastrado los sliders?

Comment: yaya, era que estaba ejecutando en la terminal y no me permitía manipular el slider, lo ejecute en CDM y aparece la gráfica y ahí si puedo usar el control. Gracias!.